# Cin is being skipped and cin.ignore is not working

Tags: c++, stream, cin

I/O redirection is needed and I cannot use fstream. I use `I/O` redirection by running the executable file with `"< input.txt"`. In my program, I use `while(cin>>line)` to read a file via `I/O` redirection. Then I need to `cin>>x ,` but this time for user input during runtime but that gets skipped.

I've tried `cin.ignore, cin.clear().`

If `cin` is used for `I/O` redirection, is it possible that `cin` can be used for user input in the same program?

```
/* Not sure if this is necessary but example of input file:
x y z
a b c
j k l
*/
string line;
while(cin>>line)
{
    cout<<line<<endl;
}

//I've tried these 2 lines but cin>>x is still being skipped
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

cout<<"Enter number: ";
int x;
cin>>x;// this is being skipped
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of the input?

Comment: So you read all the available input up to end of file for `cin`, and then you expect to be able to keep reading from it ?

Comment: @SidS no no, I know that I am reading up until the end of file. I want to use cin again, but this time for user input. do you know what I mean? sorry if it sounds confusing

Comment: So you'll have to find a way to cancel the redirection then.

Comment: @SidS Hmm, I'll see what I can find on that

Comment: Then you need a way to provide the file as an argument, read from it, and use cin as needed, without any redirection.

Comment: @mamg22 that would be a sure alternate solution but unfortunately I/O redirection is required.

Comment: _I cannot use fstream_ Why not?

Comment: @PaulSanders it is a requirement of the project but if it is not doable, then I can use fstream.

Comment: Maybe you could separate the file in sections. Section A contains the data (the "x y z"...) you need, a separator, then Section B, and so on

Comment: @mamg22 sorry, I don't follow how that would fix the user input problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't consider that the input following the data was meant to be given at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will work (untested):

```
string line;
while(cin>>line)
{
    cout<<line<<endl;
}

cin.close ();
cin.open ("/dev/tty");  // (or, on Windows, cin.open ("CON:");

...
```